# Adding a column to a data set under a certain condition of weights

Tags: r, dplyr

I am giving a data set called ChickWeight. This has the weights of chicks over a time period. I need to introduce a new variable that measures the current weight difference compared to day 0. The data set is in library(datasets) so you should have it.

```
library(dplyr)

weightgain <- ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Chick) %>%
  filter(any(Time == 21)) %>%
  mutate(weightgain = weight - first(weight))
```

I have this code, but this code just subtracts each weight by 42 which is the weight at time 0 for chick 1. I need each chick to be subtracted by its own weight at time 0 so that the weightgain column is correct.

Comment: Your code produces the correct result. I cannot replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)

ChickWeight %>%
  group_by(Chick) %>%
  mutate(weightgain = weight - weight[Time == 0])
  #Or mutate(weightgain = weight - first(weight))

# A tibble: 578 x 5
# Groups:   Chick [50]
#   weight  Time Chick Diet  weightgain
#    <dbl> <dbl> <ord> <fct> <dbl>
# 1     42     0 1     1         0
# 2     51     2 1     1         9
# 3     59     4 1     1        17
# 4     64     6 1     1        22
# 5     76     8 1     1        34
# 6     93    10 1     1        51
# 7    106    12 1     1        64
# 8    125    14 1     1        83
# 9    149    16 1     1       107
#10    171    18 1     1       129
# … with 568 more rows
```

---

Or using base R `ave`

```
with(ChickWeight, ave(weight, Chick, FUN = function(x) x - x[1]))
```

Comment: Do any of these produce different results to the code in the question?

Comment: @Marius Yes, When I run OP's code I get 540 rows whereas my code gives 578 rows. I guess `filter` is removing some rows.

Comment: Yes, I meant specifically with the weight gain variable. I can't reproduce the issue in the question, the code in the question gives weight gains relative to each chick's starting point when I try it.